# Auto rotation issues in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I am developing a custom application for ios 7 in xcode 5.i am using auto layout.I have a scene from a story board as follows. Its in the potrait mode.
[image]

when i rotate it to the landscape mode it becomes as follows
[image]

i want the landscape image o be as follows.
[image]

how can i achieve this?

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: modify autolayout constraints..thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple auto layout feature which help you to make your view like you desire.

For the view on the left, choose from the Editor\Pin menu:
Top Space to Superview
Leading Space to Superview
For the view on the right, choose:
Top Space to Superview
Trailing Space to Superview
And for the big view at the bottom:
Leading Space to Superview
Trailing Space to Superview
Bottom Space to Superview

if you want to learn auto layout there is a good tutorial fro you http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

from your question I got that you want to make the *red view* size and origin wont change after rotation.

Use width, height, left, and top in autolayout. It makes *red view* position always in top left without any size changed.

[image]

Here the results :

**Before rotation**

[image]

**After rotation**

[image]